# Is it possible to use SQL to show the average of some values in one column and then in subsequent columns display the individual values?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sequel

I have a bunch of data and I want the output to display an average of all the data points but also the individual data points in subsequent columns. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
          Compound | Subject | Avg datapoint | Datapoint Experiment 1 | Datapoint Exp 2 | ...

..........XYZ......|.....ABC....|............40...............|...............20..............................|...............60...............|......
..........TUV......|.....ABC....|............30...............|...............20..............................|...............40...............|......
..........TUV......|.....DEF....|............20...............|...............10..............................|...............30...............|......
```

One problem I'm running in to is that I get repetitive lines of information. Another is that I have some rows pulling in info that doesn't apply, such that some of the individual datapoints in, say, row 2 would have info from subject DEF when I only want it to have info from subject ABC.

I hope this makes sense! I'm currently using inner join with a ton of where qualifiers. I'm close but not quite there. Any help is appreciate and let me know if I can provide additional info to help you help me.

Comment: Please see the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), help us help you and edit your question to include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL language has a very strict rule requiring you to know the exact number of columns for your result set in advance, before looking at **any** data in your tables.

Therefore, if this average is based off a known fixed number of columns, or if the number of potential columns is reasonably small, where you can manually setup placeholders, then this will be possible. The key search terms to learn how to do this is "conditional aggregation", where you may also need to join the table to itself for each field.

Otherwise, you will need to pivot and aggregate your data in your client code or reporting tool.

Comment: Thank you for your help! So essentially, if I know the number of columns, it's doable. But if that number changes often, it is not doable?

Comment: @noobscientist That is correct.